# Error: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: formType" retrieving default view page of document library

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I'm trying to get the default view url of standard document library list in SP2010:

```
var defaltViewUrl = documentLibrary.Forms[PAGETYPE.PAGE_DEFAULTVIEW].Url;
```

and I'm constantly getting the following exception:

```
ArgumentNullException: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: formType"
```

while PAGETYPE.PAGE_DEFAULTVIEW enum value is definitely not null. Any ideas what am I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This works fine:

    var defaultViewUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", documentLibrary.ParentWeb.Url, documentLibrary.DefaultView.Url);

but the question above remains actual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default view of a list is not stored in the form collection (`SPList.Forms`).

So you indeed have to get the url of `SPList.DefaultView.Url`:

```
string absViewUrl = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(web.Url, documentLibrary.DefaultView.Url);
```

The `ArgumentNullException` occurs since SharePoint is converting the `PAGETYPE.PAGE_DEFAULTVIEW` to string. Since `PAGE_DEFAULTVIEW` is not a valid form it's converted to `null`.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works fine. 
I've also checked that SPList.Forms property returns forms only for PAGETYPE.PAGE_DISPLAYFORM, PAGETYPE.PAGE_EDITFORM and PAGETYPE.PAGE_NEWFORM so using PAGETYPE enum for indexing this prop seems to be a bad design choice